I'm getting an error on @EnableDiscoveryClient and its import statement. I'm using Gradle
the IDE window
error message

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem

This is my code:
package com.covacsis.ipf.pinot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class RegisterPinotApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RegisterPinotApplication.class, args);
    }
}

These dependencies are added:
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2023.0.2"
    }
}

I'm trying to run a spring boot scheduling application for schedule instances to a eureka-server project from the register-service project.

just "getting error"? No additional message hinting what the problem is?

Since you left us to guess as in to what the actual error is, I am going to guess it might be the same as here

@JAsgarov, I tried it, but I'm still getting the same unresolved compilation problem error.

@user85421 its unresolved compilation problem

unresolved compilation problem means you are missing a dependency. In the link I have provided it tells you which dependencies to add. You also need to do gradle build to pull the dependencies

@JAsgarov I understand. Thank you for the help

The following dependency needs to be added to gradle file  implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons'  If that doesn’t work then your IDE is not refreshing properly.  If it’s STS, delete and replace with Eclipse + Spring Tools for Eclipse rather.

@JohnWilliams I am using Eclipse.

that is not the complete error message, is it? Usually there is a second line with the actual error.  - "unresolved compilation" (@JAsgarov) means that there is a compile error - in that case some IDEs do still create a compiled .class file that will throw that exception if the corresponding code is executed - it may be missing dependency, but can be anything else, you may (must) check the IDE (Eclipse also includes the actual error message into the exception, the complete message was not posted, almost the most important information to solve any problem is the full error message)

You are missing the org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons dependency.
I have created 2 gradle projects in Eclipse, one without the dependency specified and another with:
build.gradle without dependency
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2023.0.2"
    }
}

Resulting errors as displayed in Eclipse:

I have a second project with the dependency.
build.gradle with dependency:
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2023.0.2"
    }
}

No errors in Eclipse:

If adding the dependency to build.gradle does not fix the problem then your environment, Eclipse, gradle is not working correctly. Could be anything - this needs another question.
Note that the annotation @EnableDiscoveryClient is no longer required - see here
To illustrate better the presence of @EnableDiscoveryClient in spring-cloud-commons:

